# How do I modify web scraping code to loop through product bullets until it finds correct bullet and pull information?

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

Here is my code. It pulls the "Item Model Number" off of Amazon detail pages. This has been written to find "Item Model Number" in the detail page bullet points and extract the number next to it.

The issue is that it sometimes will be unable to pull the "Item Model Number" from a page that clearly has an Item Model Number.

Here is the code

```
Sub Get_ITEM_CODE(ie As Object)
    Dim WB As Workbook
    Dim WS As Worksheet
    Dim y As String
    Dim AmUrl As String
    AmUrl = ActiveCell.Value
    ''Set WB = Workbooks.Add

    Set WS = Sheets("Extract Item COde")
    ie.Navigate AmUrl
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:02"))
    Do While ie.readyState <> 4: Loop
    On Error Resume Next

    y = ie.document.getElementById("productDetails_detailBullets_sections1").innerText

    WS.Range("A1").Value = y

    SplitTextItemCode
    AddtoListItemCode

End Sub
```

Here is a string of HTML where the Code does its job properly:

```
<div id="detailBullets" class="feature" data-feature-name="detailBullets">

<div id="detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div" data-feature-name="detailBullets" data-template-name="detailBullets" class="a-section a-spacing-none feature">
    <div id="detailBullets_feature_div">
```

[URL to webpage](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B007P07T84)

Here is a string of HTML where the Code did not do its job:

```
<div id="detailBullets" class="feature" data-feature-name="detailBullets">

<div id="detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div" data-feature-name="detailBullets" data-template-name="detailBullets" class="a-section a-spacing-none feature">
    <div id="detailBullets_feature_div">
```

[URL to Web Page](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0059AHK4A)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will loop through every "li" item under that element id. Then it will replace/remove the "Item model number:" text so you're left with a clean model number for whatever product your looking at.

> ```
> Dim Cnt As Variant
> Dim oCell As Object
> Cnt = 0  
> With ie.Document.body.all.Item("detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div").all
>     For Each oCell In .tags("li")
>         If InStr(oCell.innerText, "Item model number:") > 0 Then
>           ModelNum = oCell.innerText
>           ModelNum = VBA.Replace(ModelNum, "Item model number:  ", "")
>           Debug.Print ModelNum
>         Exit For
>         End If
>   Cnt = Cnt + 1
> Next oCell
> End With
> Set oCell = Nothing
>    End Sub
> ```

Comment: Excel needs "Cnt" and "oCell" to be defined as variables, otherwise the code is not running properly.

Comment: Correct, The cnt needs to be defined as a variable. The Ocell needs to be defined as an object...