# How Do I Test If Webpage Contains Certain Text

Tags: vba

I'm trying to detect if a web page has certain text. For example, I want to see if [this web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355762/how-do-i-modify-web-scraping-code-to-loop-through-product-bullets-until-it-finds) includes the following phrase:  "Here is my code"

I can't get it to ever find that the "If Then" condition is satisfied.  Here's what I'm trying:

```
Const READYSTATE_COMPLETE = 4
Declare Function SetForegroundWindow Lib "user32" _
Alias "SetForegroundWindow" (ByVal Hwnd As Long)As Long
' Declare Internet Explorer object
Dim IE As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
 Dim strProgramName As String

Sub Main

   ' create instance of InternetExplorer
   Set IE = New InternetExplorer
   ' using your newly created instance of Internet Explorer

  With IE
      SetForegroundWindow IE.HWND
      .Visible = True
      .Navigate2 "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355762/how-do-i-modify-web-scraping-code-to-loop-through-product-bullets-until-it-finds"

  ' Wait until page we are navigating to is loaded
      Do While .Busy
      Loop
      Do
      Loop Until .readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE
      On Error Resume Next
         If Err Then

         Else

  End If

  Wait 2


If InStr(IE.document.body.innerHTML, "Here is my code") > 0 Then

MsgBox "Yessiree Bob"

Else

MsgBox "The text dosen't exist"

End If

    Set IE = Nothing
   ' Tidy Up
End With
End Sub
```

I've also tried:

```
 FindText = InStr(1, IE.document.body.innerHTML, "Here is my code")

 If FindText > 0 Then
```

And

```
 msg = IE.document.body.innerHTML
 If InStr(msg, "Here is my code") > 0 Then
```

But nothing works. I've looked on Stack Overflow, but can't find this exact question.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Tried `document.body.innerText` ?

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
If InStr(IE.document.getElementById("body").innerHTML, "Here is my code") > 0 Then
```

Comment: Hi, if this answer got you on the right path, please tick it, or if it was something else, feel free to add that in an answer for future users!