# In VBScript how do you check if a single word in a div in IE exists?

Tags: if-statement, internet-explorer, automation, vbscript

I need to create an If statement that identifies whether or not a specific word in an IE div exists.

The reason for this is because by default, the div is empty  . When a user clicks a button to create an account, inside the div is an alert stating the user they already have an active account.

"You already have an active account, please log in"

But if the user doesn't already have an account, the div remains empty.

This is part of an ie automation tool I am creating. I'm only able to use VBScript, not VBA or anything else.

The specific word I am looking for in the div is "active".  The Div's ID is "activeAlert"

I have tried isObject, isEmpty, isNull, InStr, etc and nothing seems to be working.  Below is what I am needing to do written out in English:

```
If doc.getElementByID("activeAlert") contains the word "active" then
   msgbox("You already have an active account")
   Exit Sub
Else
   Do something
End If
```

Please keep in mind, I am still very new with using VBScript, so please explain your answers with lots of detail and any examples would would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm in favor of Étienne Laneville's answer. You can try his solution to see if it can solve your issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How Do I Test If Webpage Contains Certain Text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49060651/how-do-i-test-if-webpage-contains-certain-text) *(Although the question is about the VBA the answer is relevant to VBScript also)*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have found the element, you can check its `InnerHTML` or `InnerText`:

```
Dim objElement
Set objElement = doc.getElementByID("activeAlert")

If Not objElement Is Nothing Then
    Dim sText
    sText = objElement.InnerText
    If InStr(sText, "active") > 0 Then
        MsgBox ("You already have an active account")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        ' Not found
    End If
Else
    ' Not found
End If
```

Comment: This worked beautifully! Thank you so much!